# How to automatically click() dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that you can bind an event listener to dynamic elements, but I want to have the js automatically click them. As in, there is a webpage with a series of buttons that pop up, I want to automatically click thru them, but each successive button is loaded dynamically and so I cannot do it simply.

Here's what I was hoping would work (works if you type it into console one line at a time):

```
$(".begin").click().delay(200);

$(".answer[value='1']").click().delay(200);

$(".answer[value='10']").click().delay(200);
```

Comment: You cannot interact with something before it exists.  You must wait for the element to be created before clicking it.  Do you have access to whatever logic there is that creates the elements?

Comment: The delay should be before click(). It may not solve the problem at hand but just to tell you that delay comes between/before next action. Mostly used in animation.

Comment: @NawedKhan is correct.  `delay()` is not a replacement for `setTimeout` and is only useful for actions that use the jQuery animation queues, which `click()` does not.

Comment: `element.trigger("click")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your problem. You want to click those buttons "once" they exist. Then you might create a timer after `$('.begin')`(here I assume the begin is to trig the button appear action) and constantly check those buttons and click them once it's active. It would look something like the following with `setTimeInvertal()`. And yes you need to create your own condition to stop or determine whether trig click or not.

You have to detect them manually, faster check = once (I assume you are not doing something illegally or abusing websites). The below code is a sample idea.

```js
var btn_timer;

function startAction() {
  //for example check every 3s
  btn_timer = setTimeout(function(){
  //check if btn exists or not
  if($(".answer[value='1']").length) {
     $(".answer[value='1']").click().delay(200);
  }
  
  //condition to stop your timer, or you can manually call it somewhere else; 
  if(...some condition) StopAction();
  
  }, 3000); 
}

function StopAction() {
  clearTimeout(btn_timer);
}
```